# Using RXJS for a Search input that makes an API call but the subscribe happens repeatedly even with a debounceTime

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a search input box in html that is connected to a ViewChild in my component file.

```
<input #userSearch type="text" placeholder="Search by Name or Email...">
```

```
@ViewChild('userSearch', {static: false}) set userSearch(input: ElementRef|null) {
        if (!input) return;
        this.setInput(input);
    }

public setInput(input) {
        fromEvent(input.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .pipe(
                auditTime(1000),
                map((event:any) => {
                    return event.target.value;
                }),
                debounceTime(1000),
                distinctUntilChanged(),
            )
            .subscribe((text: string) => {
                this.count++
                console.log("count ++ is", this.count)
                this.searchTerm = text;
                console.log("this.searchTerm", this.searchTerm)
                if (this.searchTerm.length > 2) {
                    this._loadUsers({
                        search_name_or_email: this.searchTerm
                    });
                } else {
                    this._loadUsers();
                }
            });

    }
```

In my setInput function I'm using debounceTime and auditTime with the intent that when the user is done typing, that search term will be then sent off to make an api call.

The issue is that when I type in a search term "Ron", my console.log returns a count ++ of one. When i delete my search term, that subscribe gets triggered like multiple times so now my count is close to 8. When i type in a new search term, the count gets triggered to like 15. each time i delete and add a new search term, the subscribe block gets triggered repeatedly, which means the api call in this._loadUsers gets called repeatedly which is a problem.

I can't figure out why my subscribe block is being called so many times. My understanding is that with debounceTime, when the user is done typing, after the debounceTime is resolved, then the subscribe block is triggered. But for some reason, when the user is done typing, the subscribe block exponentially triggers?

UPDATE: Thanks for taking a look at this. I removed the auditTime and it still is causing issues. I've debugged the problem to this setter method in the constructor. I'm unfamiliar with this ViewChild setter method, but from some documentation I found https://blog.angularindepth.com/beware-angular-can-steal-your-time-41fe589483df (point #2) , its necessary to use when the ref input element is nested inside a *ngIf. For some reason, this setter method fires multiple times when editing the search query and I'm not sure why due to my lack of familiarity with setter methods for ViewChild.

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('userSearch', {static: false}) set userSearch(input: ElementRef|null) {
        if (!input) return;
        this.count++
        console.log("count ++ is", this.count)
        this.setInput(input);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Subject instead of fromEvent, if you are destroying and recreating the searchbox this way you only have to create a single observable chain that is reused rather than recreated every time. Your way you would need to unsubscribe from the old chain each time you hide the input. You have orphan subscriptions that are still subscribed to the input.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search by Name or Email..." (keyup)="search($event.target.value)">
```

and in the TypeScript

```
search$ = new Subject();

search(val) {
  this.search$.next(val);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.search$
        .pipe(
            auditTime(1000),
            map((event:any) => {
                return event.target.value;
            }),
            debounceTime(1000),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
        )
        .subscribe((text: string) => {
            this.count++
            console.log("count ++ is", this.count)
            this.searchTerm = text;
            console.log("this.searchTerm", this.searchTerm)
            if (this.searchTerm.length > 2) {
                this._loadUsers({
                    search_name_or_email: this.searchTerm
                });
            } else {
                this._loadUsers();
            }
        });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the auditTime seems to solve the issue

```js
const { fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { auditTime, map, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } = rxjs.operators;

fromEvent(document.getElementById('userSearch'), 'keyup')
    .pipe(
        //auditTime(1000),
        map(event => {
            return event.target.value;
        }),
        debounceTime(1000),
        distinctUntilChanged()
    )
    .subscribe(text => {
        console.log("Text is: ", text);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<input id="userSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search by Name or Email...">
```

Comment: I've updated the original post after taking a look at your response.